# Angular 2 Activated Route

Tags: angular, router

Maybe I am missing something?

In an Angular 2 component, I am simply trying to get the full Activated Route.

I do not want to use `location.href`.

My constructor is as follows:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

And in `ngOnInit()` I tried finding the value here to no avail:

```
this.route.data.url
```

Comment: `this.route.url`.

Comment: so i would assume i have to parse the array and re-construct the url with this? I was hoping the URL existed as a string in the router data somewhere.

Comment: @MikeSomeone check my answer below, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use `ActivatedRoute` for that, you need to use [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) to query for the current URL in the form of string:

```
constructor(r: Router) {
   console.log(r.url);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, both this and Hamed's answers work. Is there a best practice here?

Comment: @MikeSomeone, I would argue for my approach of course as this is standard public API for the  router

Comment: agreed, and it does not require calling the path() method.

Comment: From inside app.component this did not work for me: it always returned `'/'` (although when i logged r by itself and inspected the properties the correct url was in there). Hamed's solution works for me.

Comment: @AleshHoudek, where did you log it? Inside the App Component constructor?

Answer (score 4):

a simpler solution is to use LocationStrategy class from the `@angular/common` for representing and reading route state directly from the browser's URL which is more convenient then `this.router.url` when trying to get the router URL in form of a string.

```
  import {LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';


export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private url:LocationStrategy) { }

    ngOnInit() {
          //this will log the current url
        console.log(this.url.path());
    }

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, both this and Maximus's answers work. Is there a best practice here?

Comment: glad this helped! but I don't think there is a best practice in here but there are options and here is another one: you can inject `RouterStateSnapshot` from `@angular/router`  `constructor(state: RouterStateSnapshot)` and use it like this  `let url: string = state.url;` and by the way this method is used in the official documentation router guide.

Comment: @HamedBaatour, this will show only one url segment, same as activated route

Comment: yes that's right and I am genuinely by no means trying to argue or something (1+ on your answer) but I am just trying to give all the available options and to help as much as I can without expecting nothing in return because of my cultural and religious motives which tell me to do so.

Comment: i feel like @Maximus has the best approach. While using LocationStrategy works, it requires calling the .path() method whereas Maximus's does not.

Comment: @HamedBaatour, sure, no problem, just thought I should mention that)